No roles available in Spinnaker with OAUTH
I am trying to configure authorization in a new instance of Spinnaker, where authentication is configured with OAUTH (Azure AD) and seems to works Ok.
The problem: when I try to add permissions to application attributes, there are no roles available.

I assume that a list of groups should be retrieved from OAUTH provider, but it is not retrieved obviously.
The authz section is configured as:
authz:
  groupMembership:
    service: EXTERNAL
    google:
      roleProviderType: GOOGLE
    github:
      roleProviderType: GITHUB
    file:
      roleProviderType: FILE
    ldap:
      roleProviderType: LDAP
  enabled: true

I also tried to configure roles in a local file (with service: FILE and proper path), but this caused another issue: multiple logged errors that my OAUTH account "is missing [X-SPINNAKER-ACCOUNTS] authentication headers and will be treated as anonymous". Still the roles from the file were not visible too.
Any recommendations?

Have you added any App Roles in Azure AD app registration? Please edit your question and add those Portal images if possible
